# Recommended cloud hosting provider in the UK?

Tags: hosting, vps, web-hosting, cloud

This is the list of cloud hosting providers I know that offer their services from data centers located in the UK:

**ElasticHosts**

- http://www.elastichosts.com/

**UK2.net** (rebranded service from **VPS.net**)

- http://www.uk2.net/virtual-private-servers/
- http://vps.net/

**vhhosts** (iomart group)

- http://www.vmhosts.co.uk/
- http://www.iomart.com/cloud_hosting.php

**Rackspace Cloud** (formerly **Mosso**)

- http://www.rackspace.co.uk/Hosting-Solutions/Cloud-Hosting/Cloud-Sites/
- Not really available in the UK, yet. "They are looking to make a physical presence in the UK sometime in early 2010".

Do you have some experience with any of them? Would you recommend some?

Comment: sorry, I am a new here and Server Fault allowed me to enter only one valid URL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top 3 cloud providers are

- Amazon, that features **cloud front** from fast localized content distribution anywhere in the world *including* UK.
- Google App Engine, that basically auto-tune it geo-localization to match the one of the visitors, obviously UK is included too.
- Windows Azure (by Microsoft), not released yet, but geo-localization is already offered, and Europe (probably Ireland at first) will probably be provided in 2010.

There are many *small* cloud providers, but I think you should first consider those top three because they have huge companies backing them with correspondingly huge investments.

Comment: Well, I was not taking those into account, because:
- AWS gives only low level infrastructure. This would mean more hard work for us to set up the server environment. Being a small company, that can be too expensive.
- Google App Engine does not support PHP, and we must stick to it.
- As for Windows Azure, we don't have time to wait for 2010. And Windows is not a natural choice for PHP, either.

Anyway, thanks for your voice. Maybe you know something about those services that would clear the above doubts?

Comment: We have 3 instances in the Amazon EC2 cloud and server setup takes less than 15 minutes from scratch and less than 2 minutes using our private AMI. I'm not sure what you mean by it would be hard work to setup a server environment but I suggest you take another look at Amazon's offerings.

Answer (score 0):

I use vps.net. Very happy woth them sofar. You can migrate your data to any of their global data centres with ease.